# Authentication in supervisord

Tags: python-3.x, linux, process, xml-rpc, supervisord

I am trying to create some sort of wrapper API which can call a supervisor xml-rpc API to get some running process information and perform some starts/restarts. But when I enable username and password in supervisor conf file, I cannot authenticate using the python client. For example, the below code:

```
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy
server = ServerProxy('admin:admin@http://localhost:9001/RPC2')
server.supervisor.getAllProcessInfo()
```

Throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "supervisor1.py", line 2, in <module>
    server = ServerProxy('admin:admin@http://localhost:9001/RPC2')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1419, in __init__
    raise OSError("unsupported XML-RPC protocol")
```

I am not able to find any documentation in python docs and supervisor docs which explains how to handle authentication. And any way to make to xml-roc work with https?

I would also appreciate if anyone can point me to any alternatives which can achieve the same thing. Basically I am looking for something which can control process on a system to which I can make API calls.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Basic Authentication should look like: http://user:pass@host:port/path

In your case it should be

```
...
server = ServerProxy('http://admin:admin@localhost:9001/RPC2')
...
```